# cant get the text content of a table lxml python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

im trying to scrap the results of the lotery, the final objetive its to get the most common number of 3 digits, from the 5 digits numbers on the lotery. Im using lxml with python to get the numbers but i cant get to print the actual number, o get the xpath and try to use /text() but for some reason i keep getting an empty list. this what im using to get the number. Any suggestions? Sorry for the bad english.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page=requests.get('http://www.loteriadecordoba.com.ar/juegos/index/Loter%C3%ADa+de+C%C3%B3rdoba-18.html')

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

numero= tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/text()')

print numero
```

After some more reading  i ended up with this

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 
import time

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  
url = 'http://www.loteriadecordoba.com.ar/contenidos/juegos/0-132.html?xSorteo='
for x in range(4523 , 4525):

    url2=url+str(x)

    r = Render(url2)
    time.sleep(5)
    result = r.frame.toHtml()
    #Converting QString to Ascii for lxml to process
    formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())
    tree = html.fromstring(formatted_result)
    num= tree.xpath('//div[@class="sorteo"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/text()')
    num2= tree.xpath('//div[@class="sorteo"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/text()')
    lista = num+num2
    sorteo =open('sorteo', 'w')
    for item in lista:
        sorteo.write("%s\n" % item)

    sorteo.close()
```

i use pyQt4 to render the page the use that to read the numbers, it works perfectly on a single page, but when i run it inside a for loop it keep crashing a and posting errors

```
X Error: RenderBadGlyphSet (invalid GlyphSet parameter) 145
  Extension:    139 (RENDER)
  Minor opcode: 19 (RenderFreeGlyphSet)
  Resource id:  0x4800009
```

and now  i honestly dont have any idea :(. someone can give an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The lottery results content of that page is not present in the static HTML, it is generated/retrieved dynamically with Javascript (JQuery I think). Therefore you will not be able to scrap**e** the numbers from the page using static HTML parsers such as `lxml.html`.

Search around for another method, perhaps [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) might be useful.

Comment: yes i though in selenium but was trying to not use it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe you can analyze the javascript (I think it's using Ajax calls) and then make HTTP requests directly to those same URLs.